# What is delegate_MojoAsyncResourceHandler

Tags: google-chrome, http, http-headers

In my chrome dev tools I see this:

delegate_blocked_by = "MojoAsyncResourceHandler"

I searched online but could not find anything.

Does anyone know what MojoAsyncResourceHandler is?

Answer (score 0):

Since I also did not found any information useful to me, here is what I found:

I got the same from `chrome://net-internals/#events` after a 301 Redirect which was then cancelled.

Which should come from this class:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/content/browser/loader/mojo_async_resource_handler.cc

---

About Mojo:

> Mojo is a collection of runtime libraries providing a
>   platform-agnostic abstraction of common IPC primitives, a message IDL
>   format, and a bindings library with code generation for multiple
>   target languages to facilitate convenient message passing across
>   arbitrary inter- and intra-process boundaries.

Source:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/mojo/README.md